# Ferrite bead cases

Tags: ferrite-bead

I am migrating a design (RF) to a space grade/Hi rel design. My board has a lot of RFI or EMI filters. In my previous BOM they were of conventional dimensions (0603 and such). Now, I have to go for Hi Rel components. The component I selected belongs to an EMi filter family from [AVX](http://www.avx.com/docs/masterpubs/emift.pdf). The screen shot of the shapes of these components are attached with this post.

[image]

The data sheet recommends the following:

> For assured contact, it should be soldered directly to a bulkhead or a
>   connector base

So, how do I solder these components to my board ? WIll I need a special case ? If so, will the case have 2 metal contacts that I can solder to the board ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are feed through types - they are not designed to be used in a PCB, but for discrete wires coming through an enclosure or shield wall ("bulkhead").

Comment: any such ferrite beads for PCB ?
Ideally in the standard conventional 0603,0805,...etc or such packages.

Comment: Ferrite beads are ferrite beads- I'm not sure you'll find any special space-rated high-rel types. Lots of ordinary parts are just fine for space applications, especially LEO.